# Heroku: App not compatible with buildpack:

Tags: python, git, heroku

```
Enumerating objects: 88, done.
Counting objects: 100% (88/88), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Writing objects: 100% (88/88), 24.46 KiB | 6.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 88 (delta 42), reused 88 (delta 42)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-    registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to block-monitor.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/block-monitor.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

dir:

```
10/17/2018  09:58 PM    <DIR>          .
10/17/2018  09:58 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/05/2018  08:30 PM                93 .gitignore
10/05/2018  08:30 PM            10,283 bbot.py
10/05/2018  08:30 PM            35,966 LICENSE
10/17/2018  09:58 PM                18 Procfile
08/21/2018  06:22 PM                97 README.md
10/17/2018  09:56 PM               962 requirements.txt
10/17/2018  09:53 PM                12 runtime.txt
08/21/2018  06:22 PM                15 tokenfile.example
10/17/2018  10:02 PM                59 tokenfile.txt
10/05/2018  08:30 PM               131 tox.ini
              10 File(s)         47,636 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  128,269,000,704 bytes free
```

runtime.txt:
`python-3.7.0`

requirements.txt:

```
alabaster==0.7.11
astroid==2.0.1
async-timeout==3.0.0
atomicwrites==1.1.5
attrs==18.1.0
Babel==2.6.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
...
```

Procfile:
`worker: py bbot.py`

Sorry if the formatting is broken!
I've added everything, I have no idea why it isn't working.
Any idea? I have the Procfile, requirements.txt, and runtime.txt, all of which follow the needed casing and content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me after adding requirements.txt and runtime.txt in the root folder of my Git Repo.
Please make sure you have these files added.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error output, your app is failing to satisfy the `bin/detect` script which is used to confirm that you're really building a Python app. The detect script for the official Python buildpack is [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect).

Make sure that one of `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` is in the root directory, spelled correctly, and checked into git. Once you've done that the `detect` script should succeed and continue with the deploy.

Comment: I do! I've posted it here since I've no idea why it's working despite having everything

Comment: What's the output from `heroku buildpacks` and give `repo:purge_cache` (ref: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#purge-cache) a try before triggering another build.

Comment: `heroku buildpacks` gives `heroku/python`, and trying to purge the cache gives an error `Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later.`

Comment: If you can't purge the build cache, what happens when you push that commit to a brand new app?

Comment: It says it can't detect a language to set the buildpack

Comment: If it's throwing that on a deploy to a completely new app and you only have the `heroku/python` buildpack set then the original answer is correct. Something about your application is off. The script can't find any of the required files for that buildpack. Not sure how else to assist here, sorry.