# How to deploy a dockerized app on Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

I would like to deploy a basic Flask app on Heroku.

Here is the basic structure of my app:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app.py
├── heroku.yml
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_app.py
```

I would like the app to de re-deployed every time I merge a PR into the master branch of my project, so I set this up via an Automatic Deploy option in Heroku.

I'm able to successfully run this app locally as well as through a docker container (also locally), however, Heroku fails to deploy the app. The first error that I encountered was `No default language could be detected for this app` which led me to enable a build pack for this app (python). After setting the build pack, I get the following error: `App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz ... ! push failed`. I've found a few related discussion (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867403/heroku-app-not-compatible-with-buildpack) one) which seem to suggest that Poetry could be the problem and that I need a `requirements.txt`, but even after generating one I still get the same error.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I feel that something is fundamentally wrong because I shouldn't even need a build pack -- the docker image should take care of that. And FYI, `heroku.yml` contains the following:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Please let me know if I should share more information about my app setup.

Many thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

I've managed to push my docker image to Heroku via `heroku container:push web -a APP_NAME` followed by `heroku container:release web -a APP_NAME`, however when I open the app https://APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/ I see that it failed to start, which is not surprising as my dockerfile does not end with `RUN python app.py` -- if I add that line and rerun the above commands, then the whole process stops when the image gets built, the last line is "Running on ..." -- I don't think that running it asynchronously is the right solution here either.

Any suggestions? If I manage to get the Heroku container working, then I imagine it means I cannot get Heroku to rebuild my image every time I update the master branch, instead, I would need to do it myself.

Comment: You need to tell Heroku how to run your app. Does your Dockerfile have `CMD` instruction?

Comment: Thank you, I think I figured it out, at least partially, please see my answer below. What I'm still wondering about is whether or not Heroku offers any continuous integration tools for this deployment strategy. I know that it has the option of checking the master branch for pushes in order to redeploy the app, but if I'm deploying my own docker image, I don't think this option is available anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working. Here is what I did:

1. Change the port info inside the flask app (here is [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260338/deploying-flask-with-heroku))
2. Move `app.py` to the top level, (`appdir/app.py` as opposed to `appdir/app/app.py`)
3. Install `gunicorn`
4. Create a `Procfile` on top level of your project which should contain `web: gunicorn app:app`
5. In the Dockerfile the last line should be not `python app.py` but `gunicorn app:app`
6. run `heroku container:push web -a APP_NAME; heroku container:release web -a APP_NAME`

I still haven't worked out how Continuous Integration fits in here (in other words, does Heroku itself offer anything here?) though, so if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know

**UPDATE**

Just wanted to add that for CI I ended up using GitHub actions. I created a file under `.github/workflows/deploy.yaml` which contains the following:

```
    - name: deploy
      env:
        HEROKU_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_TOKEN }}
        HEROKU_APP_NAME: "covid-monitor"
      run: |
        heroku container:login
        heroku container:push web -a $(appname)
        heroku container:release web -a $(appname)
```

Note that for this to work you need to add the Heroku API token to GitHub secrets.